# Mono behaving slightly differently on two different machines

Tags: mono, unreal-engine4

I have several linux machines (Ubuntu 14.04) that build unreal 4 projects for me for the purposes of testing.

As part of this process mono gets invoked.  And fairly commonly mono (3.2.8) crashes with a Sigsev, which is fine.  Unreal has built in retries for that occurrence.

However on some of my Linux machines, shortly after I see a crash from mono it simply hangs.  Stack traces show it's getting a suspend signal.

What I'm wondering is why I'm getting a crash and process end on some machines, and a crash and hung process on the other.